# Black screen after installation of graphics card

Tags: graphics-card

I just bought a Radeon HD 6570 Graphics card and I put it in , installed the drivers. After about 36 hours my screen went on and off a few times and than it final went out and I couldnt get it back up. I've checked all the cords and everything was fine and it didn't over heat. I tried re downloading the drivers and that didn't work either.

Comment: Sounds like you need to RMA it.

Comment: Is it just a bad copy I got?

Comment: Could be. Try taking the card out and putting it back in.

Comment: I've done that several times

Comment: Does the computer actually boot or does it shut down after a few seconds? Have you tried a different display cable and monitor?

Comment: It will boot , but the screen just says " Going to sleep " when ever I start up my computer.

Comment: @DerekTownsend then the BIOS identified the card as functioning. Does a different graphics card (without changing cord and monitor) work? If so, the display connection on the back of your card could be dead and I would RMA.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen doesn't at least show the BIOS loading, then I would start the RMA process now. They'll probably have you go through the usual steps anyway before sending it out. No sense fiddling with it forever if it's brand new.

Comment: It doesnt do anything , It just says " Going to sleep " when ever I start up my PC.

Comment: "Going to sleep" being a message from the monitor? Have you gone back to onboard graphics and checked that it works?

Comment: Yes , while it boots up it will just say " Monitor going to sleep " than it would go off. I haven't checked it either.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your primary display setting in BIOS. The primary output device should be your graphic card, If it's you should ask for replace your card, And If the primary output device set to on-board graphic you should switch back it to your "Radeon HD 6570 Graphics card".